# Do I need to create icons other than RGBA for my Windows app?

Tags: c#, c++, windows, icons

I'm curious if anyone still creates icons other than RGB/A (or 32-bit with alpha-channel) for your Windows apps?

PS. I know that suggested model is to create 256-color versions of icons, but I always struggle with those. If I automatically convert them in an icon editor they totally decimate the look of my original icons with jagged edges and circa-Windows95 look. So if those are still required, does anyone know the stats on how many people are still using color settings other then 32-bit TrueColor?

Comment: Icons that contain 32bpp PNG images are supported since Vista.  Not on XP and probably not by your icon editor.

Comment: @Hans Nothing about PNG in the Q. Presumably we are talking about 32bpp BMP icons.

Comment: No, I'm definitely talking about icons that *contain* a PNG image.  A new-fangled icon format in Vista.  Any decent up-to-date icon editor knows how to create them.

Comment: @Hans OK, but how do PNG icons relate to this question. They are used for 256px huge Vista icons. But what has that got to do with the question?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not so much that users choose to use other than 32 bit color. The real need for 256 color icons is for when they are running over a remote desktop app that uses lower pixel depth for bandwidth efficiency.

Having said that, my experience is that apps which only load 32bpp icons still look reasonable under limited bandwith, low pixel depth remote desktop. And I suspect most people run their remote desktop with a decent pixel depth in the modern day of higher bandwidth connections

If you are going to generate 256 color icons, you usually need to create bespoke low pixel depth icons. It seldom looks good when you merge a modern alpha blended icon down to low pixel depth.

If I were you I'd try out you app over remote desktop at low bandwidth settings and see how it looks. Even if it looks a bit dirty, that may not matter to you. You may well be prepared to make that sacrifice.